# Clojure: Call a function for each element in a vector with it index

Tags: vector, clojure, loops

Say I have a vector:

```
(def data ["Hello" "World" "Test" "This"])
```

And I want to populate a table somewhere that has an api:

```
(defn setCell
  [row col value]
  (some code here))
```

Then what is the best way to get the following calls to happen:

```
(setCell 0 0 "Hello")
(setCell 0 1 "World")
(setCell 0 2 "Test")
(setCell 0 3 "This")
```

I found that the following will work:

```
(let [idv (map vector (iterate inc 0) data)]
  (doseq [[index value] idv] (setCell 0 index value)))
```

But is there a faster way that does not require a new temporary datastructure idv?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you're doing it is idiomatic (and identical to `clojure.contrib.seq-utils/indexed` in fact).  If you really want to avoid the extra data structure, you can do this:

```
(loop [data data, index 0]
  (when (seq data)
    (setCell 0 index (first data))
    (recur (rest data) (inc index))))
```

I'd use your version unless there was a good reason not to though.

Comment: Clojure 1.2 added `map-indexed` which is the simplest and best option that I've seen so far. See [Rollo's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5992602/109618).

Answer (score 29):

You can get the same effect in a very clojure-idiomatic way by just mapping the indexes along with the data.

```
(map #(setCell 0 %1 %2) (iterate inc 0) data)
```

You may want to wrap this in a `(doall` or `(doseq` to make the calls happen now. It's just fine to map an infinite seq along with the finite one because map will stop when the shortest seq runs out.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this behavior of map when applied to multiple collections.

Comment: 3 year followup: (iterate inc 0) is better written with just (range)

Answer (score 28):

A bit late in the game but for people accessing this page: there is now (since clojure 1.2) a `map-indexed` function available in clojure.core.

One issue (unless I'm mistaken): there's no "pmap" equivalent, meaning that map-indexed computations cannot easily be parallelized. In that case, I'd refer to solutions offered above.

Comment: You can do a `pmap-indexed` by including an incrementing iterator as the first collection to pmap: `(defn pmap-indexed [f coll] (pmap f (iterate inc 0) coll))`.

Answer (score 8):

The nicest way would be to use `clojure.contrib.seq-utils/indexed`, which will look like this (using destructuring):

```
(doseq [[idx val] (indexed ["Hello" "World" "Test" "This"])]
  (setCell 0 idx val))
```

Comment: As [clojure-contrib is now deprecated](http://clojure.github.io/clojure-contrib/seq-utils-api.html), where did the `indexed` function go? The [Where Did Clojure.Contrib Go](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) document doesn't seem to say anything about that.

Comment: I ended up just writing one.
`(defn indexed [coll] (map-indexed vector coll))`
just because sometimes the `(for [idx val] (indexed coll) (..))` yields clearer code than map-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I did a short comparison of the performance of the options sofar:

```
; just some function that sums stuff 
(defn testThis
  [i value]
 (def total (+ total i value)))

; our test dataset. Make it non-lazy with doall    
(def testD (doall (range 100000)))

; time using Arthur's suggestion
(def total 0.0)
(time (doall (map #(testThis %1 %2) (iterate inc 0) testD)))
(println "Total: " total)

; time using Brian's recursive version
(def total 0.0)
(time (loop [d testD i 0]
  (when (seq d)
    (testThis i (first d))
    (recur (rest d) (inc i)))))
(println "Total: " total)

; with the idiomatic indexed version
(def total 0.0)
(time (let [idv (map vector (iterate inc 0) testD)]
  (doseq [[i value] idv] (testThis i value))))
(println "Total: " total)
```

Results on my 1 core laptop:

```
   "Elapsed time: 598.224635 msecs"
   Total:  9.9999E9
   "Elapsed time: 241.573161 msecs"
   Total:  9.9999E9
   "Elapsed time: 959.050662 msecs"
   Total:  9.9999E9
```

Preliminary Conclusion:

Use the loop/recur solution.

Comment: Rich suggested when microbenchmarking to run each test a few dozen times and take the last one to get the hot-spot optimizer warmed up on the function first. testThis is much lighter weight than the map function so the tightest loop possible will be better.

Comment: I guess i need to test with hot-spot optimized.

I just ran the exact same test in Python and there it ran in 80 msec.

Comment: Write code that means what it does and does what it means. Optimize later -- at least after requirements gathered *and* complete analysis performed.

Comment: I added (dotimes [n 100] ...) around my tests and got the same results it seems hotspot can not do much about these differences.

Recur version takes about 230 msecs. Index vector about 690 msecs.

Comment: Yuck. Why are we benchmarking this at all? Unrestrained mutable state is faster than functional programming, if you think very carefully about what state your program is in when. Does that mean we shouldn't do functional programming? Of course not. Likewise, it's absurd to say "Use loop/recur" because it's faster; using `map-indexed` will often be clearer or simpler.

Comment: I know this is old but @amalloy sometimes we just want to loop over a sequence and do something that unfortunately involves mutable state i.e printing, displaying graphical, updating a database, in situations like this looping is more appropriate than using map-indexed which reads as perform a transformation on each element and return the resulting sequence, what is the return value of IO operations? nil, it would be pointless to create a new sequence of nils, in this case loop/recur is more appropriate. Besides loop/recur can hardly be called unrestrained mutable state.